# Is it possible to save crunch wordlist into multiple files?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, kali-linux

I wanted to create a 10 unit word list consisting of only the alphabets a-z, but it seems to be around 957 TB. I want to save it into two separate files, each around 5 terabyte files. Also is it possible, and how, to stop halfway and start again when using crunch?

Comment: This is a built-in function of crunch. Read the man page.